# How do I re-render form array with Ajax?

Tags: forms, hooks

In Hook_Form_Alter() there is a $form variable which changes each time the site reloads. I am working on module which does this with ajax on background. How do I re-generate $form array so I can access the newly generated variables?

Comment: Are you using the Form API #ajax element (Drupal-specific Ajax API)?

Comment: Yes I am using default Form API, and default AJAX functions provided by Drupal (ajax_command_replace())

Comment: The form is rebuilt already before the ajax callback is called. You have access to the rebuilt form in the $form variable.

Comment: Well I tested it and it is not true. Actually I have hook_form_alter() which is calling ajax on checkbox change. $form array is different depenting on which checkbox is "checked" - but I can see the difference only after reload. When I print_r $form in ajax it prints the very same array as it is already present on the site. What can I do about it? How do I retrieve re-generated $form from drupal? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ah I see. How do I access to the rebuilt form in the $form variable?

Comment: The $form variable IS the rebuilt form, so I'm not too sure what exactly you're asking.

Comment: You are true, I did not know that. Actually I found in my logs that rules fails to meet conditions when ajax is completed. So this looks like the issue actually. But it is different from that question. Thanks for explaining to me, I thought previous that $form variable holds actual form being submitted, not the new values.